# Set up stage 2 translation table ARMv8

Tags: arm, hypervisor, mmu, armv8

I am working with small/basic bare-metal Hypervisor set-up that starts in EL2, and later on switches to EL1 where
I have MMU set-up (using stage 1 translation) which is working. For instance the following snippet that sets-up the table.

````
```
uint64_t *l1_table = ((load_addr) + SZ_1M);

#if 1
    /* Only one table (which is at level 1) is used, that just shows
     * with one table we can map 1GB of address space, where VA == PA
     */
    l1_table[0] =   (uint64_t)0x0000000;
    l1_table[0] |= PT_BLOCK | PT_KERNEL | PT_AF;
    l1_table[0] |= (MT_DEVICE << 2);

    l1_table[1] = (uint64_t)0x40000000;
    l1_table[1] |= PT_BLOCK | PT_AF | PT_KERNEL;
    l1_table[1] |= (MT_NORMAL << 2);
#endif
````

I wanted to set-up stage 2 translation, where I would like to use IPA from stage 1 as an input to stage 2 translation table.

I guess, tables for stage 2 translation needed to be set-up while control is in EL2 but I don't
understand how to fetch IPA generated during stage 1 for stage 2 translation, and how table structure would look like for stage 2.

Are the PTEs for stage 2 table is based on IPA generated during stage 1 of stage 2 translation?

Comment: "... I would like to use the above set-up for stage 1 of this stage 2 translation." - what does that mean ? MMU entry has flag if that entry contain physical address to resolve virtual address or address of sub-table to continue search. You could not have same stage 1 to work with state 2

Comment: @user3124812, I corrected the statement. which MMU entry flag you're talking about ?

Comment: "Long-descriptor level 1 and level 2 descriptor formats", Descriptor bit[1] identifies the descriptor type, and is encoded as: `0, Block The descriptor gives the base address of a block of memory, and the attributes for that memory region.`, `1, Table The descriptor gives the address of the next level of translation table, and for a stage 1 translation, some attributes for that translation.`. You either have entry that specify address or entry that describes level 2 table

Comment: @user3124812, is there some example (some bare minimum Hypervisor) where stage 2 translation table set-up ?

Comment: Translation table descriptors are same for all EL. I don't know about example, but ARMv8 reference manual has detailed description on that (even with pictures)

Comment: Make sure HCR_EL2.VM is set and VTTRB_EL2 is pointing to stage2 page table. You may need to change PTE lower attributes accordingly.